# Angular 11 Panorama 360 degree image viewer

Tags: angular, 360-degrees

Is there a library that can be used with Angular 11 to view photos in 360 degree view ?

Most of the libraries i have seen have no direct support for Angular .

Can you please recommend?

Answer (score 1):

What is the format of 360º images? see if one of the examples below works.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@egjs/view360

https://naver.github.io/egjs-view3d/

https://github.com/mediamanDE/angular-three-sixty

https://www.npmjs.com/package/360-image-viewer